# Trim characters in post_meta

Tags: wordpress, trim

I have this string:

```
<span class="featrate">'. get_post_meta($key="taq_review_score",true). get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true). '</span> / 10'. '</td>
```

This gives me a value something like 96.3333333333
Is possible trim this value to show a value like 9.6

Thank you for your help

---

In database "meta_key" is "taq_review_score" and "meta_value" show values like 88.6666666667, 94.1111111111 and so one.

When I use this string

`'. get_post_meta($key="taq_review_score",true). get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true). ' / 10'. '`

This show me values like 88.6666666667, 94.1111111111 and so one.
My question is how to trim "meta_value" to show 8.8, 9.4 instead of 88.6666666667, 94.1111111111?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I need something like that <code>. get_post_meta($key="_as_rating *100)/5 , 2") . get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true).</code>

Answer (score 0):

Store your result in a variable and do the following:

```
$new_var = round($result_var);
  echo $new_var;
```

That will round it to 96.

Also have a look at the floor() and ceil() functions in PHP

Comment: is it possible for you to post some more code, perhaps I can re-write it for you

Comment: I have in the database this number 96.3333333333. I get this value with this function 'taq_review_score'. I need to transform this 96.3333333333 into 9.6. Bsed in other php file, already try $key="taq_review_score/10" but no luck.

Comment: try $key = round(taq_review_score)/10;